# How to handle scroll view for chat application when user send message in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I creating one chat application and I am getting a problem with chat scroll.
I can control scroll down when the screen opens.
I can control the scroll when sending a message

> but my problem is when another user send message i can control scroll then

thats my code :

```
  void _scrollDown() {
_controller.animateTo(
  _controller.position.maxScrollExtent + 100000,
  duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
  curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
 );
}
void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
super.initState();
_
Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 100), (timer) {
  if (mounted) {
    _scrollDown();
    timer.cancel();
  } else {
    timer.cancel();
  }
});
_controller.addListener(_scrollListstener);
}

Widget ChatMassageList() {
return FutureBuilder(
    future: _dataase
        .child('ChatRoom')
        .child(widget.chatRommId)
        .child('Chats')
        .orderByChild('time')
        .once(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        final xx = (snapshot.data as DataSnapshot).value;
        if (xx == null) {
          return const Center(
            child: Text('Send Hi To your friend...'),
          );
        }
      }
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        final massageList = <String>[];
        final isSendByList = <String>[];
        final dataList = <String>[];
        final seeList = <bool>[];
        final myrequest = Map<String, dynamic>.from(
            (snapshot.data as DataSnapshot).value);
        myrequest.forEach((key, value) {
          final nextrequst = Map<String, dynamic>.from(value);
          final massage = nextrequst['message'];
          final sendby = nextrequst['sendBy'];
          final data = nextrequst['time'];
          final see = nextrequst['see'];
          if (see == 0) {
            bool see = false;
            seeList.add(see);
          } else {
            bool see = true;
            seeList.add(see);
          }
          massageList.add(massage);
          isSendByList.add(sendby);
          dataList.add(data);
        });

        return ListView.builder(
          controller: _controller,
          itemCount: massageList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return MessageTitle(
              massageList[index],
              isSendByList[index] == user!.uid,
              dataList[index],
              seeList[index],
              pic,
            );
          },
        );
      } else {
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }
    });
```

}

and i use _scrollDown() in my send button so when i send message scroll in going down .

Answer (score 1):

By using ***reverse = true*** property of your ListView Builder you can **eliminate the use of _controller**, the reverse property will bring your newest chats to the bottom.

```
    ListView.builder(
    reverse: true,
    itemBuilder: (context, index)=> MessageTile(),
)
```

**You need to reverse all your lists that you are passing in the ListView too.**

Try this in your ListView it might solve your problem:

```
MessageTitle(
          massageList.reversed.toList()[index],
          isSendByList.reversed.toList()[index] == user!.uid,
          dataList.reversed.toList()[index],
          seeList.reversed.toList()[index],
          pic,
        );
```

Comment: I think the problem is the OP want the message to auto-scroll to bottom when there's a new message, not how to display the messages.